# Recursive expression of gradient for dynamical sytem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ and let $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$.  Consider the following discrete-time dynamical system:

$$G_{t+1} = g(G_t) ,\qquad G_0 = x.$$

Is there a recursive formula/expression for $\nabla_x G_{t+1}$ in terms of $G_t$ and $\nabla G_t$?

Comment: Unfortunate notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule
$$
∇_xG_{t+1}(x)=∇_Gg(G_t(x))\,∇_xG_t(x),~~~~ ∇_xG_0(x)=∇_xx=I.
$$